# Low-level function invocation in C?

Tags: c, function, assembly, arguments, low-level

Suppose we have a function `func` located at a known address. We know nothing about how many arguments or what kind of data types this function expects.

We are given an array which contains data that corresponds to the proper number of bytes the function would expect. For example, suppose we have function `func(uint8_t a, uint16_t b, uint8_t c)`, the array would be `0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D` where `0x0A` is the value of `a`, `0x0B0C` is the value of `b`, and `0x0D` is the value of `c`.

Given this array and the address of the function, how can this function be called either in C or in inline assembly?

EDIT: I should also mention that this code will be running on an ARM processor.

Comment: Not at all. Problem is we don't have any idea how to put it on the stack and in registers, or whatever the unknown calling-convention for that function wants.

Comment: You state that you don't know how many arguments the function takes, then state it takes 3 arguments, a byte, a short, and a byte. You can just declare a typedef for the function, then cast the address of the function to be a pointer to function of that type, and call it using the parameters you specified.

Comment: That was an example function to explain the array. All we have is the array and the function's address. We know nothing about how many arguments or what kind of data types this function expects.

Comment: push each parameter onto the stack in reverse order, call the function  upon return from the function, pop each parameter off the stack.

Comment: @user3629249 But you can't do that without knowing the size of each argument (if you have four bytes, is that four `char`s or one `int`?).

Comment: You can define a function to take an unspecified number of parameters: void *myfunc();

Comment: Could you explain why you have these restrictions, and where did the function pointer and array of arguments come from?  What you are asking is impossible, but if you take it one step back you might be able to preserve enough information to be able to call the function properly.

Comment: Thank you @JS1, very astute observation. I'm writing a communications protocol between a host PC and an ARM processor. Rather than bloat the chip with a switch statement for every possible function call, I'm trying to devise a more efficient method to do inter-architectural function calls. Each packet is 32 bytes, so whatever can be fit in there is fair game. It's just a matter of how much I can simplify the process to enable as much information to be sent via each packet.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that without knowing function calling convention. You could not just dump data in the stack and expect your function to deal with it. If it is a `__cdecl` function, you must clear stack after it execution otherwise you would corrupt it. If it is a __fastcall function, it expects first two arguments in `ecx/rcx` and `edx/rdx` registers. (And that is platform dependent too!) If it is a __thiscall, you must supply a pointer to the object instance through the `ecx` register (also platform dependent).

**Edit:**
According to the [Procedure Call Standard for the ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf), parameters could be passed through the stack and registers (pages 18, 30). So all written above still apply.

Comment: I failed to mention that this will be running on the ARM architecture, so x86 register definitions don't apply. The basic theory should be sound, however. Can you recommend an article on how arguments and the stack are related?

Comment: Correct. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the theory should still be sound. I'm working through the disassembly of my program and am devising a method in which I augment the proper registers and stack manually. Compilers are pretty predictable in terms of which registers they assign arguments to, so I'm almost certain it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Given your latest comment, I think you could accomplish what you are trying to do by passing one extra argument per function invocation (which would be the "type" of function).  For example, let's suppose you made an enumeration of all function types you will encounter:

```
enum funcType {
    V_U8_U16_U8,  // Means: void func(uint8_t, uint16_t, uint8_t)
    V_U16_U16,    // Means: void func(uint16_t, uint16_t)
    U32_U32,      // Means: uint32_t func(uint32_t)
    ...
}
```

Then on the host side, you can transmit the funcType along with the other information.  On the target side, you need to do something like this:

```
type = GetFunctypeFromStream();
switch(type) {
    case V_U8_U16_U8:
    {
        void (*func)(uint8_t, uint16_t, uint8_t) = GetFuncPointerFromStream();
        uint8_t  arg1 = GetU8ArgFromStream();
        uint16_t arg2 = GetU16ArgFromStream();
        uint8_t  arg3 = GetU8ArgFromStream();

        func(arg1, arg2, arg3);
        break;
    }
    case V_U16_U16:
    {
        void (*func)(uint16_t, uint16_t) = GetFuncPointerFromStream();
        uint16_t arg1 = GetU16ArgFromStream();
        uint16_t arg2 = GetU16ArgFromStream();

        func(arg1, arg2);
        break;
    }
    case U32_U32:
    {
        uint32_t (*func)(uint32_t) = GetFuncPointerFromStream();
        uint32_t arg1 = GetU32ArgFromStream();

        ret = func(arg1);
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course you would probably not write all of the above by hand.  You would probably auto-generate that code by writing some script to generate each case for you.  Also, signed types and unsigned types could be merged into one type because it really doesn't matter as far as calling a function is concerned.

This solution helps as long as the number of types of functions is much smaller than the number of functions.  If all of your functions are of different types, then this doesn't help because you are basically just making a switch statement of all your functions (like you said you wanted to avoid).

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation. Unfortunately, this approach isn't much better that the one I outlined in my previous comment. Following what you've done would require me to create quite a lengthy switch statement, which, as you touched on already, I'm trying to avoid. Sure, I'd save a few cases than if I were to write one for each function, but the process would still be rigorous and most likely require a script to generate accurately. As @Ari0nhh suggested, and as I was originally thinking, I may be able to achieve what I want by manipulating the stack. I'll post a followup soon

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem intreaging and gave it some time & thoughts. Let me repeat the question: you want to be able to call a function at an (any) address and want to pass it a list of arguments of arbitrary type and length. Let us define a function named "call_it" that we provide the address and a pointer to a paramter array; this function must do the stack management and the calling. Can "call_it" be a pure C function? The answer is "no" because you cannot manipulate the stack in C in the way that we must. In particular you cannot dynamicly generate the push instructions and the stack clean-up instruction(s) after the call.

You can however make brief exits to assembler to do the pushing and cleanup. Many of the other answers/participants in the discussion gave relevant aspects and examples, so I provide only a pseudo-code solution/example:

```
typedef struct PRM {int type; void *arg;};
#define T_INT   1

int call_it(int (*address)(), struct PRM *prms, int n_prms)
{
    int nbytes=0;
    prms += n_prms-1;
    for (;n_prms>0; n_prms--, prms--) {
        switch (prms->type) {
            case T_INT:
                __asm mov ax,prms.arg
                __asm push ax
                nbytes += sizeof(int);
                break;
        }
    }
    address();
    __asm add sp, nbytes;
}
```

(sorry, I only speak X86)

Answer (score -3):

Here is my shot at it. it compiles but I did not test it.

0x12345678 is a know address of the function.

assumption is that this function does not return anything.

'data' var is the data passed to it.

'data' var could also be replaced by an arbitrary struct {}.

the function would have to know how to pull the data from the address pointed to by its single pointer arg.

```
void (*fun)(void*) = (void (*)(void*))(0x12345678);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char   data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 

    fun(data);
}
```

=========

Comment: You can't specify that the function takes a void pointer, because you don't know what kind of argument the function takes, or how many. The compiler will simply pass the address of `data` to the function, making the assumption that `void *` is the argument it would take.

Comment: The whole point of the question is how to build an invokation sequence for a function with an arbitrary set of parameters, one you don't control.